# Gaussian fit to noisey data using curve_fit

Tags: python, curve-fitting, gaussian, data-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am having issues fitting a Gaussian to my data. Currently the output for my code looks like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGTH1.png). Where orange is the data, blue is the gaussian fit and green is an in-built gaussian fitter however I do not wish to use it as it never quite begins at zero and I do not have access to the code. I would like my output to look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gteCb.png) where the drawn in red is the gaussian fit.

I have tried reading about the curve_fit documentation however at best I get a fit that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXVAw.png) which fits over all the data, however, this is undesirable as I am only interested in the central peak which is my main issue - I do not know how to get curve_fit to fit a gaussian on the central peak like in the second image.

I have considered using a weights function like np.random.choice() or looking at the data file's maximum value and then looking at the second derivative at either side of the central peak to see where there are changes in inflection but am unsure how best to implement this.

How would I best go about this? I have done a lot of googling but cant quite get my head around changing curve_fit to suit my needs.

Cheers for any pointers!

This is a data file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qrAkD74U6L46GoGnvMiUHdPuLEToS6Pv/view?usp=sharing

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

plt.close('all')

fpathB4 = 'E:\.1. Work - Current Projects + Old Projects\Current Projects\PF 4MHz Laser System\.8. 1050 SYSTEM\AC traces'
fpath = fpathB4.replace('\\','/') + ('/')   
filename = '300'

with open(fpath+filename) as f:
    dataraw = f.readlines()
    FWHM = dataraw[8].split(':')[1].split()[0]
    FWHM = np.float(FWHM)
    print("##### For AC file -", filename, "#####")
    print("Auto-co guess -", FWHM, "ps")
    pulseduration = FWHM/np.sqrt(2)
    pulseduration = str(pulseduration)          
    dataraw = dataraw[15:]
    print("Pulse duration -", pulseduration, "ps" + "\n")
    time = np.array([])
    acf1 = np.array([]) #### DATA
    fit = np.array([]) #### Gaussian fit

    for k in dataraw:
        data = k.split()
        time = np.append(time, np.float(data[0]))
        acf1= np.append(acf1, np.float(data[1]))
        fit = np.append(fit, np.float(data[2]))

    n = len(time)
    y = acf1.copy()
    x = time.copy()

    mean = sum(x*y)/n
    sigma = sum(y*(x-mean)**2)/n

def gaus(x,a,x0,sigma):
    return a*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

popt,pcov = curve_fit(gaus,x,y,p0=[1,mean,sigma])

plt.plot(x,gaus(x,*popt)/np.max(gaus(x,*popt)))

figure(num=1, figsize=(8, 3), dpi=96, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k') # figsize = (length, height)
plt.plot(time, acf1/np.max(acf1), label = 'Data - ' + filename, linewidth = 1)
plt.plot(time, fit/np.max(fit), label = '$FWHM_{{\Delta t}}$ (ps) = ' + pulseduration)
plt.autoscale(enable = True, axis = 'x', tight = True)
plt.title("Auto-Correlation Data")
plt.xlabel("Time (ps)")
plt.ylabel("Intensity (a.u.)")
plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that the data are not completely Gaussian-like. It seems you have some kind of Airy/sinc function due to the time resolution of your acquisition instrument. Still, if you are only interested in the center you can still fit it using a single gaussian:

```
import fitwrap as fw
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('300', skip_blank_lines=True, skiprows=13, sep='\s+')

def gaussian_no_offset(x, x0=2, sigma=1, amp=300):
    return amp*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/sigma**2)

fw.fit(gaussian_no_offset, df.time, df.acf1)
```

[image]

```
   x0:  2.59158 +/- 0.00828    (0.3%)  initial:2
sigma:  0.373   +/- 0.0117     (3.1%)  initial:1
  amp:  355.02  +/- 9.65       (2.7%)  initial:300
```

If you want to be slightly more precise I can think of a sinc squared function for the peak and a broad gaussian offset. The fit seems nicer, but it really depends on what the data actually represents...

```
def sinc(x, x0=2.5, amp=300, width=1, amp_g=20, sigma=3):
    return amp*(np.sinc((x-x0)/width))**2 + amp_g*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/sigma**2)

fw.fit(sinc, df.time, df.acf1)
```

[image]

```
   x0:  2.58884 +/- 0.0021     (0.1%)  initial:2.5
  amp:  303.84  +/- 3.7        (1.2%)  initial:300
width:  0.49211 +/- 0.00565    (1.1%)  initial:1
amp_g:  81.32   +/- 2.11       (2.6%)  initial:20
sigma:  1.512   +/- 0.0351     (2.3%)  initial:3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a constant to the Gaussian equation, and limit the range of that in the bounds parameter of curve fit, so that the graph isn't raised higher.

So your equation would be:

```
def gaus(y0,x,a,x0,sigma):
    return y0 + a*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))
```

and the curve_fit bounds would be something like this:

```
curve_fit(..... ,bounds = [[0,a_min, x0_min, sigma_min],[0.1, a_max, x0_max, sigma_max]])
```